# What animal/insect is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I saw this animal (probably insect) in my house in the Netherlands:
[image]

[image]
I have searched on the internet but was not able to find what this is, I first thought it was a kind of dragonfly, however there are only two wings which is not usual for a dragonfly. Any suggestions what this is?

Comment: I agree with the determination, though the picture is not this clear... Green lacewings have a good appetite for aphids and other plant parasites. I suggest you could try to rear and breed it, if you have several plants within your flat. Both larva and adults exert a regular and continuous control on phytoparasites, particularly Hemiptera...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is an insect of family Chrysopidae under the order [Neuroptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroptera) (net-winged insects).
The insects of this family are commonly called [Green lacewings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_lacewing).

Neuropterans have large lateral compound eyes, [four wings](http://www.gettyimages.in/detail/photo/green-lacewing-flying-malden-gelderland-high-res-stock-photography/127474938?esource=SEO_GIS_CDN_Redirect) and a generalised pattern of veins.

[image]

<sub>(Source: [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Green_lacewing_chrysopidae.jpg))</sub>

**Identifying morphological features:**

> Soft-bodied insects with copper-colored eyes, long thread-like antennae, and lacy wings.
>
> Most species are green, but some are brown, especially [overwintering adults](http://bugguide.net/node/view/9107) of certain species

<sub>( Reference: [Bugguide](http://bugguide.net/node/view/140) )</sub>

A similar family of lacewing, [Hemerobiidae](http://bugguide.net/node/view/3577) also exists which are brown, have rounded smaller wings and found throughout the world.

*Here's a link to wikipedia showing the phylogeny of the Neuroptera as explored using mitochondrial DNA sequences: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroptera#Taxonomy_and_systematics) .*